# Python: why do I get certifcate error running a Sparql query?

Tags: python, sparql, sparqlwrapper

I have to run the following query

```
query = """
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX gn: <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#>
select ?Municipality ?Name ?Population
where
{
?Municipality a gn:A.ADM3 .
?Municipality schema:name ?Name .
?Municipality gn:population ?Population .
?Municipality <http://purl.org/dc/terms/issued> ?Date .
FILTER (?Date = "2016-01-01"^^xsd:date)
}
ORDER BY DESC(?Population)
LIMIT 5
"""
```

If I run that query here https://sparql.geo.admin.ch/sparql it works, but if I try to run it in `Python`:

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON 
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("https://sparql.geo.admin.ch/sparql")  
sparql.setQuery(query)
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
```

I get the following error

```
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

Comment: I used Google with "Python" and "CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" -> first link was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error

Comment: Regarding SPARQLWrapper I found https://github.com/RDFLib/sparqlwrapper/issues/56